# Meeting of a symmetric random walk and a random walk on integers

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, recurrence-relations, markov-chains

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be a symmetric random walk on integers and $\{Y_n\}$ be a random walk on integers with transition probabilities: 
>   $$p(k,k+1)=p,~p(k,k-1)=q=1-p.$$ 
>   Suppose $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ are independent. If $X_0=a>0,~Y_0=0$, evaluate the probability that $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ will ever meet.

**Attempt.** Let $\{(X_n,Y_n)\}$ be the $2D$ random walk on 
$\mathbb{Z}^2$ with transition probabilities: 
$$p\big((k,m),(k\pm 1,m+1)\big)=\frac{p}{2},~p\big((k,m),(k\pm 1,m-1)\big)=\frac{q}{2}.$$
If $T=\inf\{n\geqslant 0: (X_n,Y_n)\in \Delta\}$ is the time the two random walks first meet and 
$$h(k,m)=P\big((X_n,Y_n)\in \Delta|(X_0,Y_0)=(k,m)\big)$$ then we seek for $h(a,0).$ We know that:

$$h(k,m)=\frac{p}{2}\,h(k+1,m+1)+\frac{p}{2}\,h(k-1,m+1)
+\frac{1-p}{2}\,h(k+1,m-1)+\frac{1-p}{2}\,h(k-1,m-1)$$

and $h(m,m)=0$ for all integers $m,~k$. How can we procced to the solution of this recurrence equation?

Comment: I suppose $Y$ and $X$ are independent?

Comment: Of course, just edited ;-)

Comment: Is $a$ even? If $a$ is odd, $X$ and $Y$ never meet since $X-Y$ makes even sized jumps. If $a$ is even, a potentially simpler approach is to consider the $1$D random walk $X-Y$ and compute the probability of hitting $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the guideline by @Rhys Steele, let's take the $1D$ random walk $Z_n=\frac{X_n-Y_n}{2}$, defined by the semi-differences of $X_n,\,Y_n$, with transition probabilities:
$$p(k,k+1)=\frac{q}{2},~~p(k,k-1)=\frac{p}{2},~~p(k,k)=\frac{1}{2}.$$ 
Under this modelling we are looking for $P(T_0<+\infty|Z_0=a/2),$ where $$T_0=\inf\{n\geqslant 0: Z_n=0\}$$ the first time $Z_n$'s hit $0$, in other wording, $X_n$'s and $Y_n$'s coincide. Obviously the desired probability equals $0$, if $a$ is odd. For the case $a$ is even, set $h(k)=P(T_0<+\infty|Z_0=a)$ and $h$ is the least non-negative solution of the equation:

$$h(k)=\frac{q}{2}\,h(k+1)+\frac{1}{2}\,h(k)+ \frac{p}{2}\,h(k-1)$$
equivalently:
$$q\,h(k+1)-h(k)+p\,h(k-1)=0,$$

along with $h(0)=0.$ The solution to the above problem is not unique, but under the condition that $h$ is the least non-negative solution we get the formula: $$P_{a/2}(T_0<+\infty)=\left \{\begin {array}{ll}
1&~,~~0<p \leqslant 1/2\\
\displaystyle \left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^{\frac{a}{2}}&~,~~1/2<p<1\\
\end{array}
\right..$$